# %matplotlib qt5 runs but doesn't generate graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I was using this code on my Jupyter Notebook until yesterday and it was working fine:

```
%matplotlib qt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z,c='black')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
```

This morning, for no apparent reason, it started saying that there was an error with qt4 or something. After some research I installed qt5 and changed the first line of the code to "%matplotlib qt5" which now makes the code run without errors, but doesn't generate any graphs. If I take the 5 after qt I run into the message "Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: qt. Using qt5 instead.". I can still plot graphs with "%matplotlib inline", but I wanted some interactivity. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems something got updated; but with the information available it's not possible to find out what it is. In any case, since you have pyqt5 installed you may use `%matplotlib qt5`. Then you probably just forgot to type `plt.show()`?

```
%matplotlib qt5
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,4,2])
plt.show()
```

Also make sure to restart the kernel if you change the interactive backend, and if in doubt, let the line `%matplotlib qt5` appear *before* importing pyplot.